# Does a completely reducible module have to be isomorphic to a finite sum of irreducible submodules?

Tags: representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra

I suppose this is a question about the definition of completely reducible. A case I'm interested in specifically is when we have a group ring $FG$ with $G$ a finite group and $F$ a field with $\text{char } F \nmid |G|$ so that Maschke's theorem applies to say that every $FG$-module is completely reducible. Is there additional structure here (say, with the Artin-Wedderburn theorem) that makes the question true, even if it's not true in general?

Comment: This is never true. For example, take any irreducible module $M$ and consider $\bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty} M$: this is not a finite sum of irreducbile modules. However, every completely reducible module is a (non necessarily finite) direct sum of simple modules: this is just the definition, so I don't see the point of your question.

Comment: The "not necessarily finite" part was my question.

Comment: Well, in your case, every $FG$-module $M$ is an $F$-vector space. In this case $M$ is a finite sum of simple modules if and only if $\dim_F M < \infty$. This is because every simple $FG$-module has finite dimension over $F$ (it's a quotient of $FG$, which is finite dimensional).

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.